# Failed to execute "yum list": Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

OS: Oracle Linux 6

```
[xxx@host /etc]$ uname -a
Linux slc08yld 2.6.39-400.298.2.el5uek #1 SMP Mon Jan 22 13:08:39 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The error is that:

```
[xxxx@host /etc]$ yum list
file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

The yum.config:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
metadata_expire=0


[base]
name=Red Hat Linux - Base
baseurl=file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server
#baseurl=http://pd-yum-slc-01.us.oracle.com/yum/OracleLinux/EL5/GA/x86_64/base/Server


#[updates]
#name=Red Hat Linux - Updates
#baseurl=file://localhost/tmp/common/AS4.0_u1_x86_64/RedHat/Updates
proxy=http://www-proxy.us.oracle.com:80
```

Could you please tell what the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: "el5" : Support ended March 2017, for CentOS 5.11, RHEL5. I guess the same is valid for Oracle 5.11  https://distrowatch.com/?newsid=08615 . End of support means the repo mirror changes to "some old versions mirror".

Answer (score 0):

your repo is expecting to find its repository metadata in:

**file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server/repodata/repomd.xml**

but it does not exist in that path . first check the path and if the file exist and then clear your yum cache

**# yum clean**

it will also be good, if you enable DVD Repo instead